# Is laptop/desktop monitor screen a 2d array?

Tags: laptop, monitors

An image is a 2d array with each point denoting a color combination of basic RGB (one pixel, basically). So, when it is displayed or relayed to laptop/desktop monitor, how does it work? Is the monitor a 2d array, i.e, if we open up the monitor are we supposed to see any grid structure?

Comment: How does this question ask for a hardware recommendation? IMHO, it is off-topic, at least not on-topic: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a two dimensional array.

You won't see a grid, as human vision isn't good enough.

Let's engage in [gedankenexperiment](https://www.britannica.com/science/Gedankenexperiment). Let's pretend your 19" (diagonal) display is 1920x1280, in a 16:9 aspect ratio. (*Please substitute your own data for the display diagonal, horizontal, and vertical size.*) The line from A to B, or the line *c*, below is 19".

[image: Illustration of right triangle]

*c*^2 = *a*^2 + *b*^2 as per the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Pythagorean_theorem)

19*19 = *a*^2 + *b*^2

361 = *a*^2 + *b*^2  where *a* = (9/16) times *b*  (derived from our 16:9 aspect ratio)

361 = (9/16)*b* times (9/16)*b* + *b*^2

361= 81/144 times *b*^2 + *b*^2

361 = 0.5625 times *b*^2 + *b*^2

361 = 1.5625 times *b*^2

231.04 = *b*^2

15.2" = *b* which has 1,920 pixels, so there are 126.3 pixels per inch. You can't see that fine.

Comment: Just one doubt, assuming your specifications(19'' display with 16:9 aspect ratio), if an image of dimensions half that of monitor's say (960x640) is displayed, then how do all the pixels in the monitor fill up, since image only takes half space? Is the image enlarged automatically, if so do they use some kind of Nearest neighbours to do interpolation?

Comment: The method of scaling to fit a 960x640 image onto a 1920x1280 screen differs according to the app used.  That's a separate issue, and one which belongs elsewhere, such as https://SuperUser.com . The owners of this site segregate questions and their answers in order to create knowledgebases in different fields, and since they pay the bills here, their wishes are followed. See https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for what belongs here.